# Trying to make a simple 2d game, objects flashing with glutIdleFunc and glutSpecialFunc

Tags: flash, opengl, 2d

So I'm creating a simple, 2d game and I have a fish that just has to eat smaller fish. There's not really a problem with the game itself, but basically what happens is that I want other fish to move on their own, so I use the glutIdleFunc for that which works fine. However, I guess I'm not really sure on how I should make it work because I don't want that to happen until the first key is pressed. I decided to put it in my handleKey function (used to make the player move) but now my fish will disappear if the other fish move, or you can see it flashing as you hold a key down. I'm sure it's just a problem with swapping or clearing the buffer at some point, I understand you're supposed to do it once per frame, but I feel like it needs to be done as many times as I have and I can't seem to find what's causing my problem and an extra pair of eyes always helps...I'm sorry it's so lengthy and unorganized, I wanted to make it all work before cleaning it up.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //used for random numbers
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define X WIDTH/2
#define Y HEIGHT/2
#define PI 3.14159
#define INC .001



const int WIDTH = 720;
const int HEIGHT = 480;
const int numFish=10;
const int playerEyeRad=2;
const int eyeRad=1;
const int sharkEyeRad=3;


static float mouthSize = .7;
static int mouthOpen=0;
static int score=1;
static int lives=3;

bool gameRunning = true;

void *font = GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24;


struct Player
{
    int x,y;

    GLfloat deltax;
    GLfloat deltay;
    GLfloat spin;
    GLfloat scaleX;
    GLfloat scaleY;
    GLfloat scaleZ;

};


Player playerFish;


struct Fish
{
    int x,y;
    int size;
    GLfloat deltax;
    GLfloat deltay;
    GLfloat spin;
    GLfloat scale;
    bool goingLeft;
    bool goingRight;
    bool goingUp;
    bool goingDown;

};

Fish cpFish[numFish];
Fish barracuda;



char defaultMessage[] = "Fish game";
char *message = defaultMessage;

void initialize();
void output(int x, int y, char *string);
void firstDisplay();
void drawPlayer(int x, int y);
void translatePlayer(int key);
void handleKey(int key,int x,int y);  //function to handle when we press a key

void drawFish(int x, int y,int eyerad);
void setFish();
void displayFish();
void  translateFish();
void eat(int numFish);
void endGame();
void setBarracuda();
void drawBarracuda(int x, int y);
void translateBarracuda();
void barracudaEat();
void setPlayer();




int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("Fish Game");


    initialize();

    setPlayer();
    setFish();
    setBarracuda();
    glutDisplayFunc(firstDisplay);
    glutSpecialFunc(handleKey);


    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void initialize()
{
    glClearColor(.098,.14,.96,0);


    glColor3f(1,1,1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D(0,WIDTH,0,HEIGHT);


    return;

}

void output(int x, int y, char *string)
{
    int len, i;

    glRasterPos2f(x,y);

    len = (int) strlen(string);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        glutBitmapCharacter(font,string[i]);
    }

    return;
}

void firstDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    output(X,Y, message);
    output (X, Y - 40,"by");
    output(X,Y - 80,"derp");


    drawBarracuda(barracuda.x,barracuda.y);
    displayFish();
    drawPlayer(playerFish.x,playerFish.y);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();

    return;
}
void setPlayer()
{
    playerFish.x=100;
    playerFish.y=200;
    playerFish.scaleX=1;
    playerFish.scaleY=1;
    playerFish.scaleZ=1;
    playerFish.spin=0;
    playerFish.deltax=0;
    playerFish.deltay=0;

}

void drawPlayer(int x, int y)
{
    float theta;

    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // fish body
        glColor3f(.56,.035,.035);
            for(theta=0;theta<2*PI;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f(x + 20* cos(theta),y + 10 * sin(theta));
            }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //bottom of fish tail
        glColor3f(.56,.035,.035);
            glVertex2i((x-35),(y-10));
            glVertex2i((x-5),(y-5));
            glVertex2i((x-20),y);
    glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //top of fish tail
        glColor3f(.56,.035,.035);
            glVertex2i((x-35),(y+10));
            glVertex2i((x-5),y);
            glVertex2i((x-20),(y-5));
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //fish eye
        glColor3f(0,0,0);
            for(theta=0;theta<2*PI;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f((x+7) + playerEyeRad * cos(theta),(y+3) + playerEyeRad * sin(theta));
            }
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //fish mouth
        glColor3f(.098,.14,.96);
        //glColor3f(0,0,0);

            glVertex2i(112,198); 
            for(theta=-mouthSize;theta<mouthSize;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f(x + 20 * cos(theta),y + 10 * sin(theta));


            }


    glEnd();

    glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE); //stipple the gills
        short stipplePattern=0x3F07;
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);  
        glLineStipple(1,stipplePattern);
            glVertex2i(x,(y-2));
            glVertex2i((x+5),(y-2));
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glLineStipple(1,stipplePattern);
            glVertex2i(x,(y-5));
            glVertex2i((x+5),(y-5));
        glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE); //disable stipple, end of gills


            return;
}


void translatePlayer(int key)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (key==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT && (playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax) < WIDTH - 20)
    {
        playerFish.deltax+=6;
        playerFish.spin=0;
    }
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT && (playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax) > 20)
    {
        playerFish.deltax-=6;
        playerFish.spin=180;
    }
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_UP && (playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay) < HEIGHT - 20)
    {
        playerFish.deltay+=6;
        playerFish.spin=90;
    }
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_DOWN && (playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay) > 20)
    {
        playerFish.deltay-=6;
        playerFish.spin=270;
    }

    if (score%5==0)
    {
        playerFish.scaleX++;
        playerFish.scaleY++;
        playerFish.scaleZ++;
        score=1;
        playerFish.x=(playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax )* playerFish.scaleX;
        playerFish.y=(playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay) * playerFish.scaleY;
    }

    glPushMatrix(); //push on translation matrix
    glTranslatef(playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax, playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay,0.0); //translate back to position
    glScalef(playerFish.scaleX,playerFish.scaleY,playerFish.scaleZ);
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT) // stops player from going upside down
        glRotatef(playerFish.spin,0,-1,0); //reflect y axis
    else
    glRotatef(playerFish.spin,0,0,1); // spin 

    glTranslatef(-playerFish.x,-playerFish.y,0.0); //translate back to origin
    drawPlayer(playerFish.x, playerFish.y); //draw player to screen
    glPopMatrix(); // pop the matrix


    glutSwapBuffers(); //swap the buffers 
    //glFlush();

    if (!gameRunning || playerFish.scaleX>=6|| lives <=0)
    endGame();


    // mouth open close 
    if(mouthSize < .05 && mouthOpen==0)
    {
        mouthSize = .7;
        mouthOpen++;
    }
    else
    {
        mouthSize=.007; 
        mouthOpen++;
        if (mouthOpen==5)
            mouthOpen=0;        
    }

    return;
}

//function used to handle keys being pressed
//param int key ascii value of key being pressed, int x, int y coordinates the glutspecialfunc requires
//return void
void handleKey(int key,int x,int y)
{
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);//clear the buffer bit
    //drawPlayer(playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax,playerFish.y+playerFish.deltay);

    //glutIdleFunc(translateFish);
    glutIdleFunc(NULL); 
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN ||key == GLUT_KEY_UP ||key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT ||key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) // if any of the arrow keys are being pressed
    {
        if (gameRunning && playerFish.scaleX <6 && lives > 0)
        {

        translatePlayer(key); //call on the translate function using the key integer value
        glFlush();
        //glutSwapBuffers();
        //glutIdleFunc(translateFish);
        }
    }

    glutIdleFunc(translateFish);

    glFlush();
    //glutSwapBuffers();
    return;
}//end handleKey


void drawFish(int x, int y, int eyeRad)
{
    float theta;

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // fish body
        glColor3f(.8,.75,.023);
            for(theta=0;theta<2*PI;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f(x + 10* cos(theta),y + 5 * sin(theta));
            }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //bottom of fish tail
        glColor3f(.8,.75,.023);
            glVertex2i((x-15),(y-5));
            glVertex2i((x-10),y);
            glVertex2i(x,(y-5));
    glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //top of fish tail
        glColor3f(.8,.75,.023);
            glVertex2i((x-15),(y+5));
            glVertex2i(x,y);
            glVertex2i((x-10),(y-5));
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //fish eye
        glColor3f(0,0,0);
            for(theta=0;theta<2*PI;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f((x+5) + eyeRad * cos(theta),(y+3) + eyeRad * sin(theta));
            }
    glEnd();
    return;
}
//function used to set x and y values for the computer fish
//param none
//return void

void setFish()
{
    int counter;
    int randX;
    int randY;



    for(counter=0;counter<numFish;counter++)
    {
        randX = (1+rand() % (WIDTH-50));
        randY = (1+ rand() % (HEIGHT-50));

        cpFish[counter].x=randX;
        cpFish[counter].y=randY;
        cpFish[counter].size=1;
        cpFish[counter].goingUp=true;
        cpFish[counter].goingDown=false;
        cpFish[counter].goingRight=true;
        cpFish[counter].goingLeft=false;

    }
    return;
}
//function used to display the fish to the screen
void displayFish()
{

    int counter;

    for(counter=0;counter<numFish;counter++)
    {
        //cout<<"Drawing fish to screen at position: "<<cpFish[counter].x<<" \t" <<cpFish[counter].y<<endl;
        drawFish(cpFish[counter].x,cpFish[counter].y,eyeRad);

    }
    return;
}

void  translateFish()
{
    int fishNum;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for(fishNum=0;fishNum<numFish;fishNum++)
    {


            if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltax + cpFish[fishNum].x)< WIDTH - 20 && cpFish[fishNum].goingRight)
            {
            cpFish[fishNum].deltax +=3;
            cpFish[fishNum].spin=0;
                if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltax + cpFish[fishNum].x) >= WIDTH - 20)
                {
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingRight=false;
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingLeft=true;
                }
            } // end right if
            if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltax + cpFish[fishNum].x)> 20 && cpFish[fishNum].goingLeft)
            {
            cpFish[fishNum].deltax -=3;
            cpFish[fishNum].spin = 180;
                if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltax + cpFish[fishNum].x)<= 20)
                {
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingLeft=false;
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingRight=true;
                }
            }// end left if
            if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltay + cpFish[fishNum].y)< HEIGHT - 20 && cpFish[fishNum].goingUp)
            {
            cpFish[fishNum].deltay +=3;

                if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltay + cpFish[fishNum].y)>= HEIGHT - 20)
                {
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingUp=false;
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingDown=true;
                }
            } // end up if
            if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltay + cpFish[fishNum].y)> 20 && cpFish[fishNum].goingDown)
            {
            cpFish[fishNum].deltay -=3;

                if ((cpFish[fishNum].deltay + cpFish[fishNum].y) <= 20)
                {
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingDown=false;
                    cpFish[fishNum].goingUp=true;
                }
            }// end down if

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(cpFish[fishNum].x + cpFish[fishNum].deltax,cpFish[fishNum].y + cpFish[fishNum].deltay,0);
            if(cpFish[fishNum].goingLeft)
                glRotatef(cpFish[fishNum].spin,0,-1,0);
            else
            glRotatef(cpFish[fishNum].spin,0,0,1);
            glTranslatef(-cpFish[fishNum].x,-cpFish[fishNum].y,0);
            drawFish(cpFish[fishNum].x,cpFish[fishNum].y,eyeRad);
            glPopMatrix();


            eat(fishNum);


        //  cout<<"Fish "<<fishNum<<"'s deltax + x: "<<cpFish[fishNum].deltax + cpFish[fishNum].x <<" \t deltay: "<<cpFish[fishNum].deltay + cpFish[fishNum].y<<endl;
            //cout<<"Going up = "<<cpFish[fishNum].goingUp<<"going down "<<cpFish[fishNum].goingDown<<" going Right "<<cpFish[fishNum].goingRight<<"  going left "<<cpFish[fishNum].goingLeft<<endl;
    }

        translateBarracuda();
        glutSwapBuffers();
        return;
}
void eat(int numFish)
{
    int playerSize=playerFish.scaleX;
    int fishSize=cpFish[numFish].size;
    int playerX=playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax;
    int playerY = playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay;
    int cpX=cpFish[numFish].x+cpFish[numFish].deltax;
    int cpY=cpFish[numFish].y+cpFish[numFish].deltay;

    int newX = (1+rand() % (WIDTH-50));
    int newY= (1+ rand() % (HEIGHT-50));
    //cout<<"PLAYER'S X: "<<playerX<<"\t PLAYER'S Y: "<<playerY<<"\t FISH" <<numFish<<" X "<<cpX<< "\t FISH "<<numFish<<" Y: " <<cpY<<endl;
    if ((fishSize <= playerSize)&&((cpX - playerX >= (-10*playerFish.scaleX)) && (cpX - playerX <= (10*playerFish.scaleX)) )&&((cpY - playerY >= (-10*playerFish.scaleY)) &&(cpY - playerY <= (10*playerFish.scaleY))))
    {
        cpFish[numFish].x = newX;
        cpFish[numFish].y = newY;
        score++;
        cpFish[numFish].goingUp=true;
        cpFish[numFish].goingDown=false;
        cpFish[numFish].goingRight=true;
        cpFish[numFish].goingLeft=false;
        cpFish[numFish].deltax=0;
        cpFish[numFish].deltay=0;

        drawFish(cpFish[numFish].x,cpFish[numFish].y, eyeRad);

    }


    if (playerSize==6)
        gameRunning=false;

}

void endGame()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    if (!gameRunning || playerFish.scaleX>=6)
    {

        output(X,Y,"You win!");
        //exit;
    }

    else 
    {
        if (lives<=0)
        {

        output(X,Y,"Game over, you lost");
    //  exit;
        }
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void drawBarracuda(int x, int y)
{
    float theta;
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // fish body

        glColor3f(.596,.596,.576);
            for(theta=0;theta<2*PI;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f(x + 45* cos(theta),y + 10 * sin(theta));
            }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //bottom of fish tail
        glColor3f(.596,.596,.576);
            glVertex2i((x-55),(y-10));
            glVertex2i((x-25),(y-5));
            glVertex2i((x-40),y);
    glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //top of fish tail
        glColor3f(.596,.596,.576);
            glVertex2i((x-55),(y+10));
            glVertex2i((x-25),y);
            glVertex2i((x-40),(y-5));
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //fish eye
        glColor3f(0,0,0);
            for(theta=0;theta<2*PI;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f((x+7) + sharkEyeRad * cos(theta),(y+3) + sharkEyeRad * sin(theta));
            }
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //fish mouth
        glColor3f(.098,.14,.96);
        //glColor3f(0,0,0);

            glVertex2i((x+12),(y-2)); 
            for(theta=-mouthSize;theta<mouthSize;theta+=INC)
            {
                glVertex2f(x + 45 * cos(theta),y + 10 * sin(theta));


            }


    glEnd();
        glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE); //stipple the gills
        short stipplePattern=0x3F07;
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);  
        glLineStipple(1,stipplePattern);
            glVertex2i((x-10),(y-2));
            glVertex2i((x-5),(y-2));
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glLineStipple(1,stipplePattern);
            glVertex2i((x-10),(y-5));
            glVertex2i((x-5),(y-5));
        glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE); //disable stipple, end of gills

}

void setBarracuda()
{
    barracuda.x=100;
    barracuda.y=350;
    barracuda.size=3;
    barracuda.goingLeft=false;
    barracuda.goingRight=true;
    barracuda.goingUp=false;
    barracuda.goingDown=false;

}

void translateBarracuda()
{
    if ((barracuda.deltax + barracuda.x)< WIDTH - 20 && barracuda.goingRight)
            {
            barracuda.deltax +=9;
            barracuda.spin=0;
                if ((barracuda.deltax + barracuda.x) >= WIDTH - 20)
                {
                    int newX=100;
                    int newY=(1 + rand() % HEIGHT);
                    drawBarracuda(newX,newY);
                    barracuda.x=newX;
                    barracuda.y=newY;
                    barracuda.deltax=0;
                    barracuda.deltay=0;
                }
            } // end right if


            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(barracuda.x + barracuda.deltax,barracuda.y + barracuda.deltay,0);
            glRotatef(barracuda.spin,0,0,1);
            glTranslatef(-barracuda.x,-barracuda.y,0);
            drawBarracuda(barracuda.x,barracuda.y);
            glPopMatrix();

            barracudaEat();

}

void barracudaEat()
{
    int playerSize=playerFish.scaleX;
    int barracudaSize=barracuda.size;
    int barracudaPosX = barracuda.x + barracuda.deltax;
    int barracudaPosY = barracuda.y + barracuda.deltay;
    int playerX = playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax;
    int playerY = playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay;


    if ((playerSize < barracudaSize)&&((playerX - barracudaPosX >= (-10*playerFish.scaleX)) && (playerX - barracudaPosX <= (10*playerFish.scaleX)) )&&((playerY - barracudaPosY >= (-10*playerFish.scaleY)) &&(playerY - barracudaPosY <= (10*playerFish.scaleY))))
    {
        lives--;
        playerFish.x = 100;
        playerFish.y = 200;
        playerFish.deltax=0;
        playerFish.deltay=0;
        playerFish.spin=0;
        playerFish.scaleX=1;
        playerFish.scaleY=1;
        playerFish.scaleZ=1;
    if (lives==0)
    {
        endGame();

    }

    }
    else
    {
        if ((playerSize >= barracudaSize)&&((playerX - barracudaPosX >= (-10*playerFish.scaleX)) && (playerX - barracudaPosX <= (10*playerFish.scaleX)) )&&((playerY - barracudaPosY >= (-10*playerFish.scaleY)) &&(playerY - barracudaPosY <= (10*playerFish.scaleY))))
        {
            drawBarracuda(0,600);
            barracuda.x=0;
            barracuda.y=600;
            gameRunning=false;
            endGame();

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: so your main fish is flashing when the other fish [glutIdleFunc] move?

Comment: This whole thing looks a lot like a "please debug my code" question that does not really belong here. Can you at least reduce it to a minimal example of the problem that you can't resolve? Just posting your whole code and asking people to find out what's wrong with it is not the idea of this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what I would be able to reduce so other people don't get mad and say I'm not showing them everything.

Comment: @2am Yes, that's exactly what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issues and I got the game to work, thank you for everyone's input!!! I'm new to the site so I have no idea how to close the question though!

Just as an example, I took my original translatePlayer function and broke it up into an updateFunction. Everything you see in this function was taken out of the translatePlayer function

```
void updatePlayer()
{
    //opens and closes the player's mouth but not each time the key is pressed
    if(mouthSize < .05 && mouthOpen==0) 
    {
        mouthSize = .7;
        mouthOpen++;
    }
    else
    {
        mouthSize=.007; 
        mouthOpen++;
        if (mouthOpen==5)
            mouthOpen=0;        
    }

    //All the transformations for the player happen here

    glPushMatrix(); //push on translation matrix
    glTranslatef(playerFish.x + playerFish.deltax, playerFish.y + playerFish.deltay,0.0); //translate back to position
    glScalef(playerFish.scaleX,playerFish.scaleY,playerFish.scaleZ);
    if (playerFish.spin==180) // stops player from going upside down
        glRotatef(playerFish.spin,0,-1,0); //reflect y axis
    else
    glRotatef(playerFish.spin,0,0,1); // spin 

    glTranslatef(-playerFish.x,-playerFish.y,0.0); //translate back to origin
    drawPlayer(playerFish.x, playerFish.y); //draw player to screen
    glPopMatrix(); // pop the matrix

    //the player gets scaled according to the score variable, then gets reset back to 1 so the player isn't always being scaled up
        if (score%5==0)
    {
        playerFish.scaleX++;
        playerFish.scaleY++;
        playerFish.scaleZ++;
        score=1;
    }

} //end updatePlayer
```

Comment: You could add some detail on what the problem was, and how you fixed it, to your own answer here. Then accept it as the answer, so that people who come across the question later know that it has been resolved, and how.

Comment: Basically what was happening was that I was trying to draw things in too many places and too much buffer swapping and clearing, so I broke my translate functions into update functions, then put those in my display and only cleared and swapped the buffer once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` from everywhere, and having it in only one place, i.e. in the glutDisplayFunc, in this case `void firstDisplay()`

Comment: There's also `glutSwapBuffers()` in multiple places. The depth buffer is never cleared. And that's just from scanning through it very quickly, without trying to detangle the code.

Comment: I've tried that but then then nothing moves.. Also, does the firstDisplay function continuously get called? if that's the case then how come you only see text on that first screen and then never again after..If that's the case, should I just make another display function and put all the drawing in there?

Comment: you need to call glutPostRedisplay() in order to call firstDisplay for every loop.

Comment: As Datenwolf said, you are trying to display objects from more than 1 method. Ideally in a game, one should have an `init()` method which does all the initialaztions, eg loading textures, models, setting up lights, `display()` which deals only with drawing, and matrix transformations. although optional, you can also have an `update()` method. 
Also, `init` should be called only once, `update()` n `display()` you can call in your main gameloop

Comment: so with my transformations and everything, should they all be in one function as a display? If I did that, how would I use the glutSpecialFunc and glutIdleFunc - or would they just go into that new function?

Comment: @2am: Lighting setup belongs into the display function as well, since "lights" are just parameters to the illumination calculations and should be treated like transformations.

Comment: I actually fixed it by creating update methods and putting those into my dipslay function, now all I need to do is fix the ending of the game and make it actually stop updating!

Comment: @datenwolf, depends really on the situation, isn't it? if i have a scene where I dont want to move my lights, sun e.g :)

Comment: @2am: Even for fixed lights in the fixed function pipeline you have to put the `glLightfv` calls into the display functions, since the light position is transformed by the modelview matrix; so if you move your view the lights' positions need to be transformed by the moving view transformation. – Except for bulk data uploads (texture images, VBO data) it makes absolutely no sense to have any OpenGL operation outside the display routine.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule with OpenGL is: All drawing happens only from within the display routine and from nowhere else. No OpenGL commands must be called from input event handlers. Input event handlers set/accumulate into program variables and post a redraw condition. Then let the next display iteration draw the changes.

Comment: So are you saying that my translation functions shouldn't do anything with the matricies, only increment my deltas and then do the transformations somewhere else?

Comment: @user3558246: Exactly. All OpenGL operations go into the display/drawing function and nowhere else (except loading textures and VBO data).

Comment: thank you sir I didn't know how to do it at first but then it made sense!